# How to count a user created field - Orcale SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I'm looking to create a report to count the number of jobs that are logged per week.
I've created a field in the code below called "Week_Logged" however when I try and count this field I'm getting an error message saying

> SQLSTATE = S0022
>
> [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00904:"WEEK_LOGGED": Invalid identifier

Is there an easy way to count the number of jobs produced per week?

```
select
  TO_CHAR(job.actual_start_date, 'IW') as WEEK_LOGGED,
  count (WEEK_LOGGED)
      FROM
      JOB
      INNER JOIN JOB_ITEM ON JOB.JOB_NUMBER = JOB_ITEM.JOB_NUMBER
      INNER JOIN SOR_ITEM ON JOB_ITEM.SOR_ITEM_CODE = SOR_ITEM.SOR_ITEM_CODE
         WHERE
         SOR_ITEM.SOR_ITEM_CODE = 'RF-002'
GROUP BY
WEEK_LOGGED
ORDER BY
WEEK_LOGGED
```

Comment: Could you add the table descriptrion?

Comment: You cannot order/count/restrict by aliases. You either have to order by that expession itself or select it as a table inside.

Comment: ... also i wonder as this might be better rewritten using a window function to count and use distinct but not sure as example data and expected results are missing from the question ...

Answer (score 2):

Your query needs to look a little more like this;

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(actual_start_date, 'IW') week_logged,
       COUNT(*)
  FROM JOB
       INNER JOIN JOB_ITEM ON JOB.JOB_NUMBER = JOB_ITEM.JOB_NUMBER
       INNER JOIN SOR_ITEM ON JOB_ITEM.SOR_ITEM_CODE = SOR_ITEM.SOR_ITEM_CODE
 WHERE SOR_ITEM.SOR_ITEM_CODE = 'RF-002'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(actual_start_date, 'IW')
ORDER BY week_logged
```

Comment: Thank you - this brought back the data I was after.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify `GROUP BY` clause to

```
GROUP BY TO_CHAR (job.actual_start_date, 'IW')
```

and change `count` to

```
count (*)
```

it should be OK.

`ORDER BY` can still use `week_logged`, no problem.

Comment: When I've made the amendments to the COUNT and GROUP BY function it brings back an error message saying I'm missing a right parenthesis. I've looked at the brackets and can't see anything obvious missing and ( matches the number of )

Comment: Please, edit your initial message and post current code so that we could see it.